# I need to move my toast with my keyboard view

Tags: android, android-toast

I have a keyboard which I move horizontally when I am in landscape mode but for Toast I am getting it always in center of my screen though I need it in center of my keyboard.

```
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(toastContext).inflate(R.layout.toast, 
     null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
    tv.setText(text);

    mToast.setView(v);
    mToast.setDuration(duration);
    mToast.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

The expected and actual are mentioned in the image[image]

Comment: You can adjust the gravity of the toast only related to screen, not your view. If you want your toast at the bottom left, it is possible, but not what you desire

Answer (score 0):

```
Rect rec = mykeyboardcontainerview.getInputWindowRect;
int xCenter = rect.centerX();

mToast.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP, xCenter, 0);
```

The above code worked for me.